# Sql Pagination na procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou tentando implementar o **sql pagination** em minha **procedure**, já peguei diversos exemplos mas não obtive o resultado desejado.

Tenho uma procedure que faz as consultas do Lead na minha base.
Gostaria de receber na procedure alem dos filtros o **Page** (próxima pagina) e **pageSize** (Quantidade de resultados por pagina)

Segue o script da procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[BGC_SP_LEAD_SEARCH_NOVOPARTNER](
  @ID_LEAD NUMERIC(18) = NULL,
  @NR_CNPJ NUMERIC(18) = NULL,
  @DS_NOME VARCHAR(100) = NULL,
  @ST_STATUS CHAR(1) = NULL,
  @DS_BSPDIS VARCHAR(100) = NULL,
  @ID_PESSOA NUMERIC(18) = NULL,
  @ID_GERENTE VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
  @ID_TIPOPROJETO NUMERIC = NULL,
  @ID_AREANEGOCIOS INT = NULL,
  @ID_GERENTENEGOCIOS VARCHAR (50) = NULL,
  @FL_NOMEADA INT = NULL,
  @ID_USERLOGADO VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
  @ID_GERENTENEGOCIOS_LEITOR VARCHAR(50) = NULL,  
  @ID_AREANEGOCIOS_LEITOR INT  = NULL
) AS 
BEGIN
/*Procedure criada para manter compatibilidade com o EntityFramework. Procedure original: BGC_SP_LEAD_SEARCH*/
  DECLARE @ID_PESSOA_USERLOGADO VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @MASTER_USERLOGADO VARCHAR(1) = NULL,
    @ID_GRUPO_USERLOGADO VARCHAR(50) = NULL

  SELECT @ID_PESSOA_USERLOGADO = U.ID_PESSOA,
    @MASTER_USERLOGADO = U.ST_PERFIL_MASTER_BID,
    @ID_GRUPO_USERLOGADO = G.ID_GRUPOACESSO
  FROM BCS_USUARIO U
  LEFT JOIN BCS_GRUPOUSUARIOPESSOA G ON U.ID_USUARIO = G.ID_USUARIO
  WHERE U.ID_USUARIO = @ID_USERLOGADO

  SELECT DISTINCT
    LE.ID_LEAD,
    LE.ID_TIPOPROJETO,
    TP.DS_TIPOPROJETO,
    LE.DT_PREVISTA,
    LE.DT_WORKFLOW,
    LE.DS_DESENHO,
    LE.NR_VOLUMETRIA,
    LE.ST_RECURSOS,
    LE.ID_GERENTE_VERTICAL,
    LE.ID_GERENTE_PROJETO,
    ISNULL(LE.NR_CNPJ,PCLI.NR_CPFCNPJ) AS NR_CNPJ,
    LE.ID_BSPDIS,
    LE.DS_JUSTIFICATIVA,
    LE.ST_STATUS,
    ISNULL(CL.DS_NOME,PCLI.DS_NOME) AS DS_NOME,
    ISNULL(CL.DS_RAZAOSOCIAL,PCLI.DS_RAZAOSOCIAL) AS DS_RAZAOSOCIAL,
    ISNULL(CD.DS_NOME,CD.DS_RAZAOSOCIAL) AS DS_BSPDIS,
    LE.ID_RESPONSAVEL,
    US.DS_USUARIO,
    LE.ID_AREANEGOCIOS,
    LE.ID_GERENTENEGOCIOS,
    LE.ID_GERENTENEGOCIOS_LEITOR,
    CO.NR_CNPJ AS NR_CNPJ_CONTA,
    CO.FL_NOMEADA,
    null DS_CONFIDENCIAL_LEXMARK,
    EST.DS_NOME DS_BSPDIS_ESTADO,
    GN.DS_USUARIO GERENTE_NEGOCIOS,
    AN.DS_NOME AREA_NEGOCIOS,
    GNL.DS_USUARIO GERENTE_NEGOCIOS_LEITOR

  FROM BGC_LEAD LE 
  INNER JOIN BCS_USUARIO US ON LE.ID_RESPONSAVEL = US.ID_USUARIO
  LEFT JOIN BCS_GRUPOUSUARIOPESSOA GUP ON US.ID_USUARIO = GUP.ID_USUARIO
  LEFT JOIN BGC_TIPOPROJETO TP ON LE.ID_TIPOPROJETO = TP.ID_TIPOPROJETO
  INNER JOIN BCT_PESSOA CD ON LE.ID_BSPDIS = CD.ID_PESSOA
  LEFT JOIN BGC_TMP_CLIENTE CL ON CL.ID_CLIENTE = LE.ID_CLIENTE
  LEFT JOIN BCT_PESSOA PCLI ON PCLI.ID_PESSOA = LE.ID_PESSOA_CLIENTE
  LEFT JOIN BGC_CONTA CO ON LE.NR_CNPJ = CO.NR_CNPJ 
  INNER JOIN BCT_PESSOA PE ON LE.ID_BSPDIS = PE.ID_PESSOA 
  INNER JOIN BCT_PESSOATIPO PET ON PE.ID_PESSOA = PET.ID_PESSOA 
  LEFT JOIN BGC_GRUPO GR ON PET.ST_TIPO = GR.ST_TIPO 
  LEFT JOIN BCT_GRUPOPESSOA GP ON GR.ID_GRUPO = GP.ID_GRUPO 
    AND PE.ID_PESSOA = GP.ID_PESSOA
  LEFT JOIN BGC_GRUPO_GERENTE GG ON GR.ID_GRUPO = GG.ID_GRUPO
  LEFT JOIN BSP_ADDRESSBOOK AB ON CD.ID_CUSTOMERNUMBER = AB.ID_CUSTOMERNUMBER
  LEFT JOIN BCT_ESTADO EST ON AB.DS_ESTADO = EST.ID_ESTADO

  LEFT JOIN BGC_AREANEGOCIOS AN ON LE.ID_AREANEGOCIOS = AN.ID_AREANEGOCIOS  
  LEFT JOIN BGC_AREANEGOCIOS ANl ON LE.ID_AREANEGOCIOS_LEITOR = ANl.ID_AREANEGOCIOS

  LEFT JOIN BCS_USUARIO GN ON LE.ID_GERENTENEGOCIOS = GN.ID_USUARIO
  LEFT JOIN BCS_USUARIO GNL ON LE.ID_GERENTENEGOCIOS_LEITOR = GNL.ID_USUARIO  

  WHERE ---- @ID_LEAD ----
    LE.ID_LEAD = ISNULL(@ID_LEAD,ID_LEAD)
    ---- @ST_STATUS ----
    AND LE.ST_STATUS = ISNULL(@ST_STATUS,ST_STATUS) 

    AND(CL.NR_CNPJ LIKE CAST(@NR_CNPJ AS VARCHAR) + '%'
      OR PE.NR_CPFCNPJ LIKE CAST(@NR_CNPJ AS VARCHAR) + '%'
      OR @NR_CNPJ IS NULL
    )

    AND ID_BSPDIS = ISNULL(@ID_PESSOA,ID_BSPDIS)
    AND ( CL.DS_RAZAOSOCIAL LIKE '%' + @DS_NOME +'%' 
      OR CL.DS_NOME LIKE '%' + @DS_NOME + '%'
      OR @DS_NOME IS NULL     )




     AND ( CD.DS_RAZAOSOCIAL LIKE '%' + @DS_BSPDIS +'%'
      OR CD.DS_NOME LIKE '%' + @DS_BSPDIS + '%' 
      OR @DS_BSPDIS IS NULL    )




    AND ( LE.ID_AREANEGOCIOS = @ID_AREANEGOCIOS OR @ID_AREANEGOCIOS IS NULL)
    AND ( LE.ID_AREANEGOCIOS_LEITOR = @ID_AREANEGOCIOS_LEITOR OR @ID_AREANEGOCIOS_LEITOR IS NULL)
    AND ( LE.ID_GERENTENEGOCIOS = @ID_GERENTENEGOCIOS OR @ID_GERENTENEGOCIOS IS NULL    )
    AND ( LE.ID_GERENTENEGOCIOS_LEITOR = @ID_GERENTENEGOCIOS_LEITOR OR @ID_GERENTENEGOCIOS_LEITOR IS NULL    )


    AND (CO.FL_NOMEADA = @FL_NOMEADA OR ( CO.FL_NOMEADA IS NULL 
        AND @FL_NOMEADA =2
      )
      OR (@FL_NOMEADA IS NULL) 
    )
    AND ( LE.ID_TIPOPROJETO = @ID_TIPOPROJETO
      OR @ID_TIPOPROJETO is null
    )
    AND ( @ID_USERLOGADO IS NULL
      OR GG.ID_GERENTE = @ID_USERLOGADO-- GERENTE DO GRUPO ASSIGNACAO
      OR LE.ID_BSPDIS = @ID_PESSOA_USERLOGADO -- É DO MESMO CLIENTE QUE CRIOU O LEAD
      OR LE.ID_RESPONSAVEL like '%' + @ID_USERLOGADO + '%' -- É O CRIADOR DO LEAD
      OR LE.ID_GERENTENEGOCIOS = @ID_USERLOGADO -- GERENTE DE NOGOCIOS DO LEAD
      OR @ID_USERLOGADO IN (SELECT ID_VERTICAL FROM BGC_AREANEGOCIOS WHERE ID_AREANEGOCIOS = LE.ID_AREANEGOCIOS) --GERENTE VERTICAL
      OR @ID_USERLOGADO IN (SELECT ID_GERENTE FROM BGC_TIPO_GERENTE_LEAD WHERE ID_TIPO_GERENTE LIKE 'C')
      OR @ID_USERLOGADO IN (
        SELECT usr_prf.ID_USUARIO
        FROM BCS_PERFIL prf, BCS_USUARIOPERFIL usr_prf
        WHERE prf.ID_PERFIL = usr_prf.ID_PERFIL
        AND prf.DS_PERFIL = 'Gerente Comercial Canal'
        OR prf.DS_PERFIL = 'Administrador - Gestão de Canais'
      )
      OR @MASTER_USERLOGADO = 'S'
      OR (GUP.ID_GRUPOACESSO = @ID_GRUPO_USERLOGADO )--OR @ID_GRUPO_USERLOGADO IS NULL )
    )
  ORDER BY
    DS_BSPDIS, DS_NOME, DS_RAZAOSOCIAL, LE.DT_PREVISTA 

END
```